# How to properly use loop in Cypress?

Tags: loops, cypress

I have a login page. When I click on Login button, it redirects to Dashboard. But sometimes, instead of redirecting to Dashboard, it returns the same Login page. In this situation, I want to loop through Login until the page gets redirected to Dashboard.
Any suggestions?

```html
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1073">
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained 
  jss1068 MuiButton-containedPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button">
    <span class="MuiButton-label">Login</span>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I have used
cy.visit('....')
to go to login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let count = 0
function login() {
  cy.visit(url)
  cy.contains('Login').click().then(() => {
    //cy.wait() Apply wait if you have to
    //Assert presence of any element from the Dashboard Page
    if (count <= 5 && Cypress.$(selector).length == 1) {
      return
    } else if (count <= 5) {
      count++
      login()
    } else if (count > 5) {
      return
    }
  })
}
login()
```

The recursive function will run 5 times before completely exiting. You can change the count value as per your requirement. Also to prevent cross-origin errors write in your `cypress.json`

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Comment: Which selector should I use in if-block? And what should I return? Also, do I include 'login click' and 'any dashboard element' before if statement?

Comment: Any element on the dashboard page. It can be a button or some input box etc. The idea is to make sure that the Dashboard page is loaded and the element is present in the DOM. If the redirection happens after login then you have to write it after cy. Visit(). For login you just have to click the login button ?

Comment: I think your code works fine. But it seems login on my end is pretty messed up. When clicked on login, it will load and bring up the same page again, but then this time login is clicked automatically. And only then enters Dashboard. If after page load, login is not automatically clicked, then that is where the problem arises. Thank you for your efforts. But unless this problem on my end is solved, the code you shared will only loop through continuously without moving on to next step.